# RxJS: correct patterns for identifying stream source in combined stream?

Tags: javascript, stream, rxjs, rxjs5, frp

I am looking for some best-practice suggestions on how to identify which stream is coming in to a `merge` or `combineLatest` function in such a way that only the new stream is operated on.

In the context of a TODO app, I have incoming add and remove streams, and I want to combine them so that my list editing can occur within a single stream in a stateless manner. The output is a list that has integrated both add(concat) and remove(filter) events, otherwise you seem to end up with other streams that include all the add or remove events and thus grow infinitely.

Problems encountered include:

- using `merge` does not indicate which stream is incoming;
- using `combineLatest` does not indicate which stream has triggered the subscribed stream, so you can't only perform the operations relevant to that stream.
- using `withLatestFrom` results in a new list that does not update the `withLatestFrom` input source, so unless the next stream also interested in this list subscribes to that list, the list will get out of sync (or you have every new list based on the one before it, which causes needless re-stepping through every transformation for those that happened prior to it...).

Currently found approaches that somehow seem sub-optimal include:

- The Cycle JS TODO app explicitly assigns `type` properties directly to the created objects of the earlier streams for identification, which I would have thought should be avoided in favor of using RxJS methods that directly identify where the streams come from?
- taking the suggestion from http://www.jisaacks.com/manipulating-rxjs-streams/ and splitting the output of addition streams and removal streams to `[null, {addItem}]` and `[removeItem, {null}]`, such that when using `merge` for both add and remove events, I could still identify the incoming stream which was being updated, so that I could perform both addition and removal in a single stream (but then I want to add toggle events, etc, but this doesn't seem right either since I'm needing to create stream outputs that are aware of all the other potential streams (ending up with [null, null, myOutput, null, null etc].

Any best practice suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Rxjs method which allows to identify where a stream comes from. Streams do not carry a name on them. If you want one, you need to put it yourself. So find another way to put a name on them if you like none of those two ways. If your question is what is the best practice to put an identifier on an object, then the answer is put an identifier on the damn object.

The way I personally favour is through a curried function :

```
function label(identifier){return function (x){var obj={};obj[identifier]=x;return obj;};}
```

which I use as follows:

```
source1.map(label('remove')).merge(source2.map(label('add')))
```

but really, do as you please, how you do this is a rather minor issue, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks very much. It may seem minor in your experience but I just felt there must be some different way that I had missed (and was therefore not doing in the correct Rx way) in particular to identify which particular stream had updated when using `combineLatest`. So I actually thought this was really important to get correct and the correct pattern (ie just put an identifier on the object) is not made clear as being the correct approach anywhere, so not sure why my question has been down-voted. In any case I'll just use `merge` along with your labelling function, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate exact stream before merging to avoid unnecessary id handling. In general with streams and functional programming, try to avoid if-else structures as there are tools made to help you out. Usually you can avoid it by looking where the call is made and act a little bit earlier.

Here is an example. List operations are just pseudo to get most important parts visible.

```
let listSubject: Rx.Subject<Item[]> = new Rx.BehaviourSubject<Item[]>([]);
let addObs: Rx.Observable<Item[]> = initAddObs();
let removeObs: Rx.Observable<Item[]> = initRemoveObs();

Rx.Observable
  .merge([
    addObs.map(items => (list: Item[]) => list.concat(items)),
    removeObs.map(items => (list: Item[]) => list.filter(items))
  ])
  .withLatestFrom(listSubject, (operation, list) => operation(list))
  .subscribe(listSubject)
```

For the list there is used BehaviourSubject so anyone get the latest situation no matter when they subscribe. AddObs and removeObs streams are mapped to operations, which have same signature and can be merged. After the operation is performed against current list we have to recycle result back to listSubject. Now you can subscribe to listSubject and you will get up-to-date list emitted from there.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is indeed the case and I have since learnt that .withLatestFrom memoizes each state and so calling it doesn't 'trigger' everything to chain through as I initially thought. Unfortunately the question has already been answered and I have marked it as such, so I can't also mark yours as answering the question though it is also correct.